# MySql Database stopped working LAMP

Tags: mysql, linux

After making system update (my SO is Ubuntu 18.04) and reboot, the mysql doesn't start on Xampp. 
Here is the `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` :

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.7-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
```

Here is the log :

```
 2018-07-25 10:08:29 17051 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.34-MariaDB) starting as process 17200 ...
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1774708 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 1774798 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/gtid_slave_pos in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 3, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 2, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 1, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 4, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__central_columns in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 20, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__column_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 5, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__designer_settings in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 21, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__export_templates in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 22, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__favorite in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 9, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__history in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 6, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 18, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__pdf_pages in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 7, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__recent in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 8, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__relation in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 11, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__savedsearches in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 19, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_coords in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 12, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 13, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_uiprefs in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 10, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__tracking in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 14, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 15, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__usergroups in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 17, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__users in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 16, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.39-83.1 started; log sequence number 1774798
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649284552448 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-07-25 10:08:30 139649694680896 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2018-07-25 10:08:30 17051 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/kmms-VirtualBox.pid ended
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: The clue is "Have you deleted or moved .ibd files?".  Even if you undo the file manipulation (and possibly permissions), you will find that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be more than a tiny 16M; try 100M.

Comment: how can i find that? There is any command to check that?

Comment: Start by checking the `my.cnf` file.

Comment: my.cnf should be on "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/" right? if yes, i dont have it (actually, neither this "/etc/mysql/" i have)